# Rails 4 ajax proccessing as html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to get ajax working for my contact form and currently I'm trying to test to make sure the ajax is getting called.

In my console I can see that it's still getting processed as HTML and I cant figure out why.

```
#app/views/contact_mailer/_contact_me.html.haml
= form_for @message, url: contact_path, authenticity_token: true, remote: true do |f|
  = render 'layouts/error_messages', object: f.object
  = render 'layouts/flash'
  = f.label :name
  = f.text_field :name, :placeholder => 'Enter your your name...'

  = f.label :email
  = f.text_field :email, :placeholder => 'Enter your email address...'

  = f.label :subject
  = f.text_field :subject ,:placeholder => 'Enter your subject...'

  = f.label :body
  = f.text_area :body, :placeholder => 'Enter your message...', :size => '25x15'

  = f.button 'Send', :id => 'send-button', :class => 'darkgreen-button'
```

Somewhere In my messagesController I also need to fit a call to ContactMailer.contact_me(@message) but I'm not quite sure where I would add that.

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def contact
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @message.valid?
        format.html { redirect_to contact_path, notice: 'Message was sent successfully.' }
        format.js {  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      else
        format.html { render file: 'pages/contact' }
        format.js { }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Finally I try to respond with a console log but it never shows up

```
#app/views/messsages/contact.js.haml
console.log("AJAX Called!")
```

*EDIT Application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//
//= require analytics.js.coffee
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require_tree ./global
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `{ }` from the end of format.js.

Because you are providing a block you are asking the controller to override the default file i.e. app/views/messages/contact.js.haml. By having the {} you are telling the controller to render what is in your block instead of rendering that file.

Update: issue resolved by including the two JQuery libraries if you are trying to use JQuery:

//= require jquery 
//= require jquery_ujs

Comment: Processing by MessagesController#contact as HTML is still the result of removing the {}

Comment: Do you see this on the HTML that is generated in the page? data-remote='true'

Comment: Yep I do see it in the generated HTML

Comment: Try adding <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %> to the head of your layouts, i.e. in application.html.erb or _head.html.erb. The required JS file might be missing. Also, check in the Firefox dev tools or FireBug if you have it that the request is being made back to the server with the accept: application/javascript attribute or similar. You should also see the response and request quite clearly.

Comment: I'm getting a 404 http://localhost:3000/javascripts/defaults.js Ill post my application.js. Where do I check for the application/javascript request in firebug?

Comment: Showing my age. <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> is what it is now. Can we use the chat? There wis a chat link down the bottom, then go to the room "Ruby on Rails". http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5676/ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 0):

Why not try this:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def contact
    @message = Message.new(message_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @message.save
        format.html { redirect_to contact_path, notice: 'Message was sent successfully.' }
        format.js                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      else
        format.html { render file: 'pages/contact' }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def message_params
      params.require(:message).permit(:message, :params)
  end
end
```

To help you debug, you've got to look at how this works. When you send a `remote: true` request, it will be sent as a `js` request - that's standard.

---

**Open your console & show us the request**. It should say:

> [image]
>
> If it's not JS, your problem is you're not passing a valid AJAX request

---

**Use `alert` when testing JS response**

Console never seems to work with Rails, a far more robust approach is to use `alert`:

```
#app/views/messsages/contact.js
alert("Ajax Called");
```